# If $t = \frac{(2-x)(3-x)}{3x^2 -7x + 6 }$, then find $\frac{-x^4 + 2x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x}{3x^2 -7x + 6 }$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $t =\frac{(2-x)(3-x)}{3x^2 -7x + 6 }$.  Can you, please, give me any hints to express the following in terms of $t$:

$$\frac{-x^4 + 2x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x}{3x^2 -7x + 6 }?$$

Answer (score 1):

1-Firstly, expand numerator of the given equation like
$$t=\frac{x^2-5x+6}{3x^2-7x+6}$$
2-Don't do anything with the denominator because denominator is same in the required answer.
3-Multiply $t$ by $-x^2$, to get $-x^4 $ term.
4-Then, make the same terms which you required by adding and subtracting terms.
5-At the end, you have$$-x^2t+\frac{-3x^3+3x^2+2x}{3x^2-7x+6}=\frac{-x^4+2x^3-3x^2+2x}{3x^2-7x+6}$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wanted to express that only with $t$ because if not theres no point to it.
He needs to express $x$ in terms of $t$, which can  be obtained after hard work from the given formula, and then substitute.

Comment: @MuhammadWasi as Theoniix has pointed out, I need to express it only with $t$.  I cant see how I can use your suggestion to do that

Comment: What I think is that we have two options to express it in only _t_ . First, we multiply some number to _t_, it wouldn't help us to increase the power of _x_ from 2 to 4. Or Second, if we square _t_ to get the x^4 then it would also increase denominator's degree by 2.

Comment: But, there is no change in degree of denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Cross multiply the definition of $t$ to get $t(3x^2-7x+6) = (x^2-5x+6)$.  Write the whole business as a polynomial in $x$:  $(3t-1)x^2 +(-7t+5)x +(6t-6) = 0$.  Use the quadratic formula to get $x= \frac{7t-5 \pm\sqrt{(-7t+5)^2 - 4(3t-1)(6t-6)}}{2(3t-1)}$ and simplify a little.  Plug this monstrosity in for $x$ in your expression and may God have mercy on your soul.